# Angular ng-repeat animation on delete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-animations

I am trying to create an add\remove animation in an ng-repeat (with css transitions).
For some reason the fade out effect always happens at the bottom of the list and not on the item you choose to delete (for example try deleting the first item , the effect shows at the bottom) . 
Here's a plunkr 
http://plnkr.co/edit/XdGHKhf5z5BQMaYk1Naz?p=preview

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you remove

```
track by $index
```

, then it should be all right.
just:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" class="repeat-item">
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a simple `ng-repeat: "item in items"` in this way works fine.

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7OHzRg0dJxvzKfvpuR6u)